# Set a hotkey to show an auto-hiding Plasma panel?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I've set my Plasma panel to auto-hide.

How do i map a hotkey to pop out the panel so that i can have a look at it without moving my hand off the keyboard to the mouse and then dragging the mouse all the way down the screen?

I've looked into the Global Keyboard Shortcuts control, found the Plasma Desktop Shell section, but failed to find a relevant item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Toggle Panel | Panel Toggle**

There are (at least) two plasmoids to toggle the panel visibility. Both have the option to add the keyboard shortcut.

From the old KDE svn playground: http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/playground/base/plasma/applets/togglepanel/

From the KDE-Apps.org: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=149654

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Both plasmoids can only be installed via make, with no uninstall option?

Comment: They are bot using the cmake - Kubuntu forums - 'How to uninstall something installed with cmake' : https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63090-How-to-uninstall-something-installed-with-cmake . Some binaries are available from the Ubuntu PPA system: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=plasma-widget-togglepanel

Answer (score 3):

If you want to manage it without installing additional widgets you can place a ‘Bouncy Ball’ to the panel and assign shortcut to it. Also you can assign shortcut for a clock (digital / analog / binary – doesn’t matter) widget, it has side effect of showing whole panel along with calendar.

Comment: This won't work. The hotkey will bring the panel up and then immediately hide it.

Comment: @lolmaus Since it’s undocumented feature, it’s quite possible that it works for me at KDE 4.8.4-3 and doesn’t work for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a kwin script that toggle panel

https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1266534/

We can also add more feature to a panel by setting it up in (KDE System Settings - Window Manager - Window Rules - New - Detect Window Properties "And select your pannel"