# Set a shortcut to un-hide kde panel on Plasma 5

Tags: kde, panel, kde5, plasma-5

I have a panel with task manager on the left side of the desktop. It is set to auto-hide mode. I want to know if there is a way to set a shortcut which un-hides the panel as long as the key is pressed (same effect as in Unity).

I found a similar question: [Set a hotkey to show an auto-hiding Plasma panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396588/set-a-hotkey-to-show-an-auto-hiding-plasma-panel) but it was asked for KDE 4 desktop. The apps given in the solution does not work on plasma 5.

Comment: ideally, we should have one question to cover all versions. If you get an answer, maybe this question could be merged into the older one